# Define a Multidimensional Array

Tags: java

Today I am asking a for help on a snippet of code that is confusing me, I am probably just misunderstanding its use and haven't been able to find the proper keywords to find an answer.

```
Ex. 1

    int[][] position = new int[22][2];

    position[0][0] = 11;
    position[0][1] = 32;


Ex. 2

    int[][] position = new int[22][2];

    position[0] = {11, 32};
```

Above I have provided the snippet of an array which holds predefined chunks of data. I want to set the data using one line (like in example 2) to accomplish the same thing I am accomplishing in example 1 with two lines.

If someone could help me out on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks, Dustin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
int[][] position = new int[22][2];
position[0] = new int[]{11, 32};
```

If you have all the data available you can make it even shorter by intializing your array  like this:

```
int[][] position = { { 11, 32 }, { 1, 2 } };
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, I should have known that. Thanks for the quick reply but I am going to give the accepted answer to Adam as he replied first and with a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Dustin: You can of course give the checkmark to anyone, but I did answer first.

Comment: It shows Adam's at 'answered 7 mins ago' and yours at 'answered 8 mins ago'. :(

Comment: @Dustin: Exactly, I was a minute (almost) ahead.

Comment: Ah yes, it appears I have dug myself into a bit of a, "fail" here.. You sha'll win, hah.. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine those lines into this:

```
position[0] = new int[]{11, 32};
```

although I think that in most cases you are better off with a `List` (`ArrayList` for example). Of course it depends on the task at hand.

If you want to initialize the whole array at once you can do this:

```
int[][] position = new int[][]{{11,32}, {12,32}}; // ...
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, this is exactly what I was looking for! I am glad the both of you understood exactly what I was asking. For my specific goal at hand I would prefer to just use an array than an arrayList. Thanks again!